Upload a Contact Group as a discrete file to SharePoint, which others could then import into their own Outlook?
I have a Contact Group (newer term for "distribution list") in Outlook that I'm trying to upload to a folder in SharePoint.
Drag and drop of the object (let's call it List101) from my People folder in Outlook to a SharePoint folder open in my browser leads to a file named List101.msg being created, which is an Outlook email that is devoid of any of the actual contacts contained in the group.
From Outlook, tried File => Save As, and there's no CSV option, just Text, Rich Text, and three Outlook-specific file types. Output in Text produces a plain text file with spurious file info at the top followed by a tab-delimited list of the contacts of List101.
Searching on Microsoft's support site, I have no need to synchronize contacts between Outlook and SharePoint with respect to this list. I want to simply be able to have List101 be a static, manually-maintained list that if needed can be drag-and-dropped into another user's People folder.
Of course, a possible solution is to Ctrl-A to select all the contacts in List101, then paste those into Notepad, then have the user create a new, local Contact Group on their end, Add Members, then paste the text file contents into the textbox at bottom of that dialog. Too many steps vs just having a prepped file available to just drag-and-drop and if need be overwrite the existing.
In other words, I want to treat this Outlook-SharePoint interaction as if moving file-like objects between them, but at first glance here it's more complicated than I'd like.
Creating a Contact Group in my organization's Exchange is not possible in my situation. Thanks in advance for any suggestions that would conform to my admittedly weird constraints.

Export group as .vcf, vCard, file, readable by many devices (phones, PC's, etc.): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-contacts-as-vcards-ee4f63f4-94f9-4861-8340-4517590d9459 [A vCard can also be viewed as a text file.]

Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, export to vCard saw the resulting file attachment in the draft email appears as a plain text file same as described above, List101.txt, tab delimited and basically identical.

Can you export to the desktop or to download folder? Something is wrong if it does not save in the vCard format.

Are you sharing contact groups with others through SharePoint, and they can import them into their own Outlook account?
